# Hibernate One To Many join column not Saving

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Hibernate and Spring/ Spring MVC.
I have two entities, AccommodationRequest and Restriction.
The relationship is AccommodationRequest can have many Restriction.

When I save the AccommodationRequest with a Restriction, both the results are saved to the database
but the Restriction is missing the foreign key / join column (accommodationRequestId).
I am sure there is something I must be missing. Any help is appreciated.

AccommodationRequest is defined:

```
@Entity
public class AccommodationRequest {
....

@OneToMany(mappedBy="accommodationRequest",
        targetEntity=Restriction.class,
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Restriction> restrictions;


public List<Restriction> getRestrictions(){
    return restrictions;
}

public void setRestrictions(List<Restriction> restrictions){
    this.restrictions = restrictions;
}
....
```

Restriction is defined:

```
@Entity
public class Restriction {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

private String restriction;



@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="accommodationRequestId")
private AccommodationRequest accommodationRequest;

public AccommodationRequest getAccommodationRequest() {
    return accommodationRequest;
}

public void setAccommodationRequest(AccommodationRequest accommodationRequest) {
    this.accommodationRequest = accommodationRequest;
}
```

And below is the code that does the saving:

```
Restriction restriction = new Restriction();
restriction.setRestriction("test restrcition 6");
List<Restriction> restrictions = new ArrayList<Restriction>();
restrictions.add(restriction);
long id = accommodationService.saveOrUpdate(accommodationRequest);
accommodationRequest.setRestrictions(restrictions);
accommodationService.saveOrUpdate(accommodationRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set AccommodationRequest to your Restriction.

```
Restriction restriction = new Restriction();
restriction.setRestriction("test restrcition 6");
restriction.setAccommodationRequest(accommodationRequest); // You have to do this
List<Restriction> restrictions = new ArrayList<Restriction>();
restrictions.add(restriction);
long id = accommodationService.saveOrUpdate(accommodationRequest);
accommodationRequest.setRestrictions(restrictions);
accommodationService.saveOrUpdate(accommodationRequest);
```